# How disable cache for a PHP file which includes a HTML part

Tags: php, html

I created a a HTML page with a PHP file. Inside this php script, it is possible to modify speech files.
This modification works fine, but if I try to play the modified file, the browser only plays the old cached file and not he modified new file.

My PHP script has two parts, first the PHP code and on the end the HTML code.

**Already tested solutions**

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate" />
```

But this is not working. I found comments, that most browsers are ignoring the meta tags. Therefore I included the following code on the beginning of the php section.

```
<?php
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 19:03:12 GMT');
```

But also this modification doesn't solved my problem.
Even when I look at the source code of the HTML page, I can not see anything from the PHP headers. Do I have add anything in the HTML section? Or what should I try to disable the browser cache for this PHP HTML page?

**Update 2023-02-07 17:45**

Find out to view the headers. Had to click into the related document under the Network tab.
Here are the results:

[image]

It looks to me, that the wished header information was sent, but the client still displayed the cached file. I also want to point out, that I'm using the file in the following way:

```
<div class="col-1 px-0 mx-0">
<img src="/typo3conf/ext/album/Resources/Public/Icons/Speaker_Icon.svg" height="20" title="Hörprobe 15s" class="aSpeaker" data-music="https://www.country-radio.eu/fileadmin/Radio/Voice/TTS/Hans-Georg_Althoff_HGA_1.mp3">
</div>
```

The file name is embedded into a img tag. But even, if the header information is received by the client browser, the caching for the file is still activated.

Comment: Headers you set using `header()` are headers for the HTTP response, not the HTML page so they won't be visible when watching the HTML source. What exactly is cached? The HTML/PHP file or some asset you load (like some audio file?) If it's an asset, then it's most likely that asset that is cached, not the PHP/HTML. To solve that, you could add a random string to the URL: `http://path/to/file.wav?<?= uniqid() ?>` or something.

Comment: _"but if I try to play the modified file, the browser only plays the old cached file"_ - so you would need to send the appropriate caching header for _that_ file - and not your HTML document.

Comment: Use the "Network" tab of your browser developer tools. It shows you the header values as well.

Comment: Peter,
I use Firefox and went into the developer tool with <shift>F5. Under network analysis I could not find any header values.

Comment: Apparently it is also called "Network" in Firefox. [Blog: How to Capture Network Logs from Firefox Web Browser](https://support.panopto.com/s/article/How-to-Capture-Network-Logs-from-Firefox-Web-Browser)

Comment: **M. Erikson**
Ok, that is a work around for the problem, but not really solve the cache problem.

Comment: **CBroe**

I have not found, how to implement a caching header for the file. Do you have some additional information or a link?

Comment: Peter, the link you have send to me seems to be an older Firefox version. I am using a german version and it shows me instead of network "Netzwerkanalyse". But the headers are still the same. 
Even when I gress Ctrl F5 to refresh the page, I dont see any header information, only html, js, css and images. Even when I have selected all.
Does it means, there are no hesders send from the server?

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple...
You can use the **clearstatcache()** function.
By using this You can Clear the cache and run the modified file
Here under is an example in php.

```
    <?php
   // check filesize
   echo filesize("/PhpProject/sample.txt");
   echo "\n";

   $file = fopen("/PhpProject/sample.txt", "a+");
   // truncate file
   ftruncate($file, 100);
   fclose($file);

   // Clear cache and check filesize again
   clearstatcache();
   echo filesize("/PhpProject/sample.txt"); 
?>
```

Whose Output will be:

```
25
100
```

Hope this solves the problem...

Comment: I have added the `clearstatcache()` command after I have made the changes at the audio file. But the problem is the same!
But how should it solve the problem?
The `clearstatcache()` is running on the server and the file is cached on the browser of the client?